# Can Android SDK tools be installed in Scala IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools, scala-ide

I have [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/) installed and I want to add the Android SDK Tools to it. I'd rather not download the ADT Bundle and have 2 different copies of Eclipse on my system.

Can the SDK Tools be safely installed into Scala IDE, and how? Also will there be any further dependencies to install, or does Scala IDE contain everything needed for the SDK? I'm rather new to Eclipse and Android and I don't want to risk messing something up.

Comment: Looks like it might be possible. http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/androiddevelopment/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try ? :)

Both Scala IDE and the Android SDK are available as plugins for Eclipse ([Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html), [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)). And there is an extra plugin useful to simplify the configuration of a Scala + Android project ([AndroidProguardScala](https://github.com/banshee/AndroidProguardScala)). All the needed dependencies should get pulled automatically.

Finally, there is [a short tutorial](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/androiddevelopment/index.html) to tweak the example Android app for Scala. I didn't test it with the latest versions of everything, but it used to work very well.

On a side note, I would advise you to setup different Eclipse for different purposes. It is usually an better idea than trying to cram all the features you may need in one Eclipse installation.